# Java OOP HomeWork

Tags: java, object-oriented, homework

My professor is super strict and just want to know if I have solved this correctly.

Design a class named Location for locating a maximal value and its location in a two-dimensional array. The class contains public data fields row, column, and maxValue that store the maximal value and its indices in a two-dimensional array with row and column as int types and maxValue as a double type.
Write the following method that returns the location of the largest element in a two-dimensional array:

```
  public static Location locateLargest(double[][] a)
```

The code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Please enter the row and column size");
        int row = kk.nextInt();
        int column = kk.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the values between 1 and 10");
        double[][] d = getArray(row,column);

        Location l = locateLargest(d);
        System.out.println(l.toString());

}

    public static double[][] getArray(int row,int column){
        double [][] a = new double[row][column];
        double input;

        for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++){

                a[i][j] = kk.nextDouble();
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    public static Location locateLargest(double[][] a){

        int rowIndex=0;
        int columIndex=0;
        double max = a[rowIndex][columIndex];

        for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++){

                if (a[i][i]>max) {
                    max = a[i][j];
                    rowIndex=i;
                    columIndex=j;
                }
            }
        }

        return new Location(rowIndex,columIndex,max);
    }
}

class Location{

    int row,column;
    double maxValue;

    Location(){

    }

    Location(int row,int column,double maxValue){
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
        this.maxValue = maxValue;
    }

    public String toString(){

        return "The largest value is "+maxValue+" at row "+row+" and column "+column;
    }

}
```

Comment: There is nothing object-oriented in this code, so you should have chosen a better title.

Comment: Does that code compile at all?

Comment: "just want to know if I have solved this correctly" Code posted at Code Review should work to the best of your knowledge. If you don't know, it's not ready for review.

Comment: It is to the best of my knowledge because Im a beginner. This is code review no? Where I can have my code reviewed and receive feedback to gain knowledge. Everybody here likes to make a big deal of all the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The class `Location` must be a `public class Location` since it doesn't make sense to have a `public` method with a non-`public` return type.
- The fields of the `Location` class must be `public int` and `public double`, since the task description​ says so.
- The fields of the `Location` class should be `public final int` and `public final double` since they won't change after being initialized once.
- The no-arguments constructor then contains a compilation error and should be removed completely.
- You should let the IDE format your code so that it is nice to read: `Ctrl+Shift+F` in Eclipse, or `Ctrl+Alt+L` in IntelliJ.
- Your implementation is completely correct, congratulations.

Comment: Great tips! Is my formatting wrong? IntelliJ says it's properly formatted

Comment: At least the spacing is inconsistent. And there should be a space after each comma.

Comment: I think the formatting became issue with the copy paste to this site. You should paste it as is here, then selec all and press the `{}` button at the top of the editor.